# How to fix: compare two sheets & output matches code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a current code that is supposed to compare tables in sheet1 to sheet2 and output the matches in another sheet(sheet3). When trying to run the code, I am getting "Type mismatch" error" and I'm not sure what is wrong nor how to fix it...

Picture of VBA code and the second table/sheet:
[image]

```
Sub CompareSolve()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim ar As Variant

ar = Sheet2.Cells(10, 1).CurrentRegion.Value

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
.CompareMode = 1
    For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)
       .Item(ar(i, 1)) = Empty
    Next

ar = Sheet1.Cells(10, 1).CurrentRegion.Value
n = 1

For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)
    If .exists(ar(i, 1)) Then
       n = n + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
                   ar(n, j) = ar(i, j)
           Next j
   End If
Next i
End With
Sheet3.Cells(10, 8).Resize(n, UBound(ar, 2)).Value = ar
End Sub
```

These two tables are in the same position on the sheets for these 2 sheets

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: @Tom `For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)`

Comment: I suspect your array is empty and the `UBound` function is failing. I can't see in your picture what the range is applied to but it looks like you want `ar = Sheet2.Cells(10, 3).CurrentRegion.Value` (i.e. the `CurrentRegion` starting on the 10th row

Comment: @Tom I changed that and now I am getting the same error for the second line that has `For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)`

Comment: I'd suspect it is similar for your other sheet but can't see it. If you're going to use `CurrentRegion` the first cell referenced needs to be the first cell of the region you want to select. If the first cell you specify is empty it will return nothing, and if all of the cells surrounding it are empty it will only return the first cell.

Comment: @Tom i edited my post with the new code. The other sheet has the exact same format(with the table starting at (10,3). I don't know what else to change that is giving me empty data

Comment: Update it with the same cell reference i.e. `ar = Sheet1.Cells(10, 3).CurrentRegion.Value` The way you're referencing it is actually selecting cell `J1`

Comment: @Tom I fixed it, but it seems to output a full row if only the first column of the first sheet matches the value of the first column in the second sheet. I am looking to have the code output the row if the ENTIRE row matches. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I'm sure there is but I would close this question and raise a new one to your new issue as this is no longer related and your initial issue is now solved

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code thanks to help from @Tom

````
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim ar As Variant

ar = Sheet2.Cells(10, 1).CurrentRegion.Value

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
.CompareMode = 1
    For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)
       .Item(ar(i, 1)) = Empty
    Next

ar = Sheet1.Cells(10, 1).CurrentRegion.Value
n = 1

For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)
    If .exists(ar(i, 1)) Then
       n = n + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
                   ar(n, j) = ar(i, j)
           Next j
   End If
Next i
End With
Sheet3.Cells(10, 8).Resize(n, UBound(ar, 2)).Value = ar
End Sub```
````